# Simulating error on opening a file for reading

Tags: python-3.x, linux, unit-testing

#### Motivation:

I want to be able to test a scenario, where my function can't open some file for writing (appending actually, but I don't think this matter) and I want to be able to distinguish this situation from "file does not exist" one.

#### Example:

```
import os
from stat import S_IREAD, S_IRGRP, S_IROTH
from typing import Optional
from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory
import unittest

DEFAULT_VAL = 100
def myfunc(fname: str) -> Optional[int]:
    if not os.path.isfile(fname):
        return DEFAULT_VAL
    try:
        with open(fname, 'at') as f:
            return f.write('bar')
    except IOError as e:
        return None

class TestMyFunc(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_read_file_when_ok(self):
        with TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdir:
            fn = os.path.join(tmpdir, 'foo.txt')
            with open(fn, 'wt') as f:
                f.write('')
            self.assertEqual(myfunc(fn), 3)

    def test_default_when_file_does_not_exist(self):
        with TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdir:
            fn = os.path.join(tmpdir, 'foo.txt')
            self.assertEqual(myfunc(fn), DEFAULT_VAL)

    def test_None_when_fails(self):
        with TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdir:
            fn = os.path.join(tmpdir, 'foo.txt')
            with open(fn, 'wt') as f:
                f.write('')
            os.chmod(fn, S_IREAD | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH) # make it read only
            self.assertIsNone(myfunc(fn))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

As you can see, I'm testing this by making the file read-only, which works
*perfectly fine*:

```
$ python3 a.py
...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.001s

OK
```

..that is **until it failed** on bitbucket, because in docker, pipelines run
under `root`.

And `root` has no problem with opening read only files for writing:

```
$ sudo python3 a.py
F..
======================================================================
FAIL: test_None_when_fails (__main__.TestMyFunc)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 36, in test_None_when_fails
    self.assertIsNone(myfunc(fn))
AssertionError: 3 is not None

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

#### My fallback solution:

I know I can refactor my code (which is unfortunatelly much larger than `myfunc` example) to accept some "file opener" where I can inject some mock which would raise appropriate exception, but I would very much prefer solution which does not require refactoring existing code and which could be isolated in the test.
This is my fallback if there's no other simple (and clean, no monkey-patching) solution.

#### What I'm looking/hoping for:

I sort-of feel/hope there may be some simple solution based on modifying the file or directory properties..

#### Question:

Is there a simpler way to simulate "can't open file for writing" so it:

- would work even for root
- would be distinguishable from "file not found"
- would work on linux (i.e. I don't need to support any other platform than Linux)

?

(GNU/Linux Debian 10, python3)

Comment: The basic issue is you need a file created with different rights.  i.e. a file that is owned by someone other than 'root'. If that user doesn't exist in the container, you'll need to update the dockerfile to create one.

Comment: @MarcelWilson wouldn't root be able to open that file too? That's the main problem - root can open any file regardless of the permissions (as far as I know and as far as "normal" filesystem goes)..

Comment: I think you may be correct.  Inverting the users ought to solve that.  So create a user which runs the tests and try to access a file that root owns.

Comment: @MarcelWilson yes, you are technically correct, that would work. But while it would solve this exact case, when someone else somewhere else would run it under root it would "magicaly" fail again - I would rather make it work regardless of current user than just make this specific case work. You see - I view it more like "oh, I made a mistake, and that docker pipeline helped me to find it" than "this is perfectly good code, it's not my fault someone is running it as root!" :)  - so I do WANT it to be able to run even under root.

Comment: Oh, I agree.  This is not a fun problem since it relies on testing user permissions. It would be great if python had something like `open().as_user()` but since it doesn't, it requires that you run this test under a different user than the one that created the file.  At that point the whole thing can't really be run atomically in a neat python script.   You'd have check the assumption that the script is running as a particular user prior to the test itself.

Comment: As @jan-spurny points out, my suggestion doesn't really solve your problem since you're looking for this to work even under root.  As far as I can see, the only way that would work would be to "fake it" using something like mock.

Comment: Have you tried the command `chattr +i foo.txt` ?

Comment: @Phillippe - no, but now that I have - it doesn't work under docker: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/522621/in-docker-chattr-operation-not-permitted-while-setting-flags-on-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could mock `open` itself:

```
def test_None_when_fails(self):
    with TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdir:
        fn = os.path.join(tmpdir, 'foo.txt')
        with open(fn, 'wt') as f:
            f.write('')

        m = unittest.mock.mock_open()
        m.side_effect = PermissionError()
        with unittest.mock.patch('__main__.open', m):
            self.assertIsNone(myfunc(fn))
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't want to do any patching, but I was not aware of `unittest.mock.mock_open()` - that looks like a very clean solution.. thank you!